# "show in finder" open the file instead of opening the directory containing it

Tags: macos, finder

the problem appeared after i tried path finder app, i didn't like it, i removed it using cleanmymac, than i used

`defaults write -g NSFileViewer -string com.apple.Finder`

and
 `rm Library/preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

now every time i click on show in finder, instead of opening the folder containing the file( the default behaviour of finder), it open the file, for EXP: if the file is a dmg it mount it, if it's a text file it open it on an editor, would any one have any idea how to reset finder

Comment: have you tried relaunching the finder?

Comment: to relaunch finder, hold option key and right-click on finder icon in dock. Last option is Relaunch. Click that option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but to reset Finder you should relaunch it. To relaunch the Finder, hold down the option key and right-click on the Finder icon in the dock. A list of options will appear. The last option is Relaunch. Click that and the Finder will relaunch.

To relaunch from the terminal: open the terminal and type:

> `killall Finder`

'

Comment: no it doesn't resolve the problem, thanks anyway